# Best option for unknown number of child windows in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, silverlight, childwindow

I have to migrate some forms made in Silverlight to ASP.NET. This forms include a lot of child windows that, at the same time, may contain other several child windows as well. This child windows should be able to communicate to their parent windows.

I've looked into `window.open(url,params)`, also to `window.showModelessDialog` (I don't like this one as is IE only) and having multiple div's and hiding/showing them accordingly.

With the first option, `window.open` I thinks there's problems when opening multiple child windows and controlling their postback, `window.showModelessDialog` is IE only and I don't want to drop other browsers support. And having multiple divs hide/shown is tedious, as it would mean having a whole page populated with divs and not loading child windows dynamically or easy enough.

What's the best option to accomplish this? Am I missing another one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution has been to use [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form) to create dialogs. They're not actual Internet Explorer windows which makes it very easy to communicate with your page. And they're cross platform compatible.

It's likely that other client side libraries would suit you just fine.

Comment: I don't know how I missed jQuery UI! Thanks for reminding me. I'll use jQuery UI loading an iframe from an external URL, I think it'll be the best option. Thanks again!

Comment: Uh, are you sure you want to do an iFrame? Why don't you just use Panel's?

Comment: Why is it better to use Panels? (true curiosity) I've always found this server-client-postback thing kindda dirty, with iframes it's all client-side handled and I fail to see Panel's advantages over jQuery UI.

Comment: I'm not saying don't use jQuery UI. But I'm saying don't embed iFrames. The only way I would embed an iFrame is if I knew the data being posted back from the iFrame would not need to go to the parent window. But that's kind of the point of having child windows-the data is tied to the parent. So I'd just use a Panel. iFrames can't communicate back to the parent windows very easily.

Comment: If they're in the same domain there shouldn't be any problems, as I understand. I was planning on passing data through events, as a child window can be opened from several different parents. Are there any problems with this approach? (Yes, I hate this <asp: controls)

Comment: In general, it's just not necessary to use iFrames, as all their advantages can be accomplished in other ways. There's no reason to mindlessly hate ASP.NET Controls, you just learn when you need them and when to use their plain HTML equivalents. In you case, you could launch a modal dialog as a window, and it can show content from a div or asp:Panel and pass data much more easily back to the parent page. You cannot easily pass data back to the page when using an iFrame.